# Xcode crashes running an empty app on device

Tags: xcode, debugging, crash

Following this tutorial, http://codewithchris.com/deploy-your-app-on-an-iphone/ Xcode crashes when I run the app on my phone. On the simulator it is working. There's no warning before the crash. I tried running a completely empty app, but no luck.

I'm using Xcode 6 and an iPhone 4s with iOS 8.1.3.

The log from the Xcode crash report says this:

> Application Specific Information:
>   ProductBuildVersion: 6C121
>   ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-6760/DVTFoundation/FilePaths/DVTFilePath.m:802
>   Details:  fsrep is relative ('גÄ‮-‬‭/‬גÄ‮,‬var/folders/6g/y36l5n813bd3kch53qp4w60h0000gn/CגÄ‮-‬‭/‬גÄ‮,‬‭/‬com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.2‭/‬Xcode') parentPath must not be nil but it is.

but I don't understand it; does anyone know what this means?

Comment: Is Xcode crashing right away when you click on the "run" button? Are you running xcode in full screen mode? if so, try pressing cmd+r instead. There's a bug with the close / minimize / maximize buttons invisibly overlaying the run / stop buttons...

Comment: If you're saying that Xcode itself is crashing, I would first try creating a new user account on your machine and run it from there.  If it still crashes in a new account, delete Xcode and re-install.  (If it's OK in the new account, there is something messed up in your preferences.)

Comment: If your app is crashing, you'll need to read the log to see why it's crashing. Even the simplest of bugs in your code can crash an app.

Comment: Hey -Toastor thank you for your'e comment , I tried your tip and did cmd+r it is still crashing right away. Hey -Phillip Mills thank you for your'e comment, I'd opened a new user didn't helped to what should I do?. Hey --Marcus Adams thank you for your'e comment here I  added part of the log can you help me understand it and maybe solve it please it would be great.

Comment: Does the "/6.2/Xcode" part mean that you're using a beta version of Xcode?  If so, delete it and use the release version...or report your error on the beta section of Apple's developer forum.